# how to display chinese character in txt file on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: chinese, character-set

I tried some methods to fix this issue,but no lucky.I can't find the auto-detected item to configure it.So what I should do next,I need help,and thanks a lot!

Comment: You probably need to install language support for Chinese via Settings -> Language Support .  Try that first

Comment: I did it and no changes

Answer (score 0):

I am suffering this same issue while using `vim`.

Add these lines to `vimrc` where located at `/etc/vim/vimrc`

```
set fileencodings=utf-8,gb2312,gbk,gb18030
set termencoding=utf-8
set encoding=prc
```

Save and run `source /etc/vim/vimrc`.

Comment: OP isn't asking about **vim**