# won't render chinese characters in txt files

Tags: command-line, fonts, language-support, character-set

Pretty much would say same post as this

[how to display chinese character in txt file on ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803504/how-to-display-chinese-character-in-txt-file-on-ubuntu-16-04)

I went to language support and installed both simplified / traditional chinese but when I open up the .txt which I believe is opened with gedit and I see encoded words.  I don't need to type Chinese inputs, as long as I can read them.

P.S. if my .txt file is named in chinese my system do read it though for example chinese.txt (which chinese is of course encoded chinese characters)

Edit:
This is how the texts looks like

`ubuntu 12.04/64Î»/4ºË4G/50GÊýŸÝÅÌ    --->²âÊÔok
ubuntu 12.04/64Î»/1ºË512M/ÎÞÊýŸÝÅÌ   --->²âÊÔok`

Comment: Actually, fonts for rendering Chinese contents is installed by default in Ubuntu, so it ought to work also before you had installed the full language support. It would help if you could edit your question and attach a sample text file and a screenshot which shows what it looks like for you.

Comment: Could be an encoding issue. Were the .txt files created in Windows?

Comment: Thanks, Dora. As @ace said, it's probably about encoding. Is there any chance that you could provide a link to an *original* text file with this problem? That way we might be able to figure out its encoding.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson it was a within a private zip file which I won't be able to provide. But I also realized, when I use the inspect window from chrome and in html there are some chinese characters I can read but in source when I check some css files, the chinese characters there wouldn't render.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson the txt file I am talking about, if I use windows instead of ubuntu the text file would render though

Comment: You can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/805418/3488231. Try to determine the encoding first. Then you can either (i) convert the file to UTF-8 encoding; or (ii) tell gedit to open the file with a different encoding (see http://askubuntu.com/q/282672/274080).